# How to use OpenSSL on XBox One

Tags: windows, visual-c++, openssl, xbox-one

OpenSSL support a lot of systems, but that is not support XBox One, because XBox One only C++ compiler so there is no way to support?

Separate from OpenSSL some of the algorithms seem very troublesome, if I want to use XBox One above encryption algorithm should be how to do?

Comment: *"but that is not support xboxone, because xboxone only c++ compiler so there is no way to support..."* - You should probably show how you are configuring and compiling; and the errors you are encountering. OpenSSL must be built with a C compiler; see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. You can force MSVC into "C mode" with the `/Tp` option; see [/Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Microsoft has their own crypto libraries built into Windows, they are probably in the Xbox One too.  Can you use those?